# fail in running the opencv sample in android

Tags: android, opencv

Recently,i want to learn how to use opencv in android,but I stuck in the beginning.

I follow [this page](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/android_binary_package_using_with_NDK.html#android-binary-package-with-ndk) to learn how to construct the environment,but when I run the sample "Tutorial 1-Add OpenCV",it appears [image: this warming]

The environment:

jdk 1.6  33update

eclipse juno

android 4.0

ndk r8b

Anybody know what kind of mistakes I have made?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you actually read warning message? It says that your program doesn't work without [OpenCV manager](http://opencv.itseez.com/android/service/doc/Intro.html). It was added in version 2.4.2. So all you need to do is to install it.

Comment: Of course,I have read this message.this project is form the opencv_android_2.4.2.I followed the guide,but it just didn't work……

Comment: I really haven't installed OpenCV manager..I took for granted that it will be installed automatically when I ran the emulator.I can run the sample now..Thank you..~